# Create union of array from an object

Tags: arrays, object, lodash

Input:

```
var foo = {
    event: {
      fields: ['title'],
      joins: {
        session: ['name', 'venue']
      }
    },
    session: {
      fields: ['name', 'venue']
    },
    person: {
      fields: ['name']
    }
  }
```

Output the unique values from fields:

```
['title', 'name', 'venue']
```

What I have tried so far:

```
_.filter(foo, _.pick(fields))
```

Comment: Is this `foo` object structure static? Or other fields could be added?

Comment: It is static object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (read more about [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce)). See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tevadikiyi/edit?js,console)

```
_.uniq(//_.reduce finally will return array, pass it to _.uniq to leave only uniq values
   _.reduce(foo, function(result, value, prop) {//get all properties on the 1st level and try find fields array among them
      if (_.isArray(value.fields)) {
         //is such array is found - add its values to the result array
         result.push.apply(result, value.fields);
      }
      return result;
   }, [])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_(foo)
    .pluck('fields')
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

The first step is to use [pluck()](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) to get an array of `fields` arrays. However, we want to use [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) to get a *flat* array of strings, duplicates are still included at this point. The last step is to use [uniq()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) to remove the duplicates.

Comment: adding `.compact` method will be better to avoid falsy values?